# Perform multi click event on a single image in Android

Tags: android, image-processing, opengl-es

suppose take my example as PIANO image..on every key press on its keyboard i want to perform a different event..now i am not able to get where to start this..
how to perform this in android..

take below image:

[image]

As  you can see in the image i have an piano image..and drawn red and blue lines in some shape..now i want to perform different event for each shape on this image..
how can i do this in android programming..

Comment: You could calculate Collision Detection, when the users touches anywhere on the screen.

Comment: @Vallentin buddy but it is a single image..do you have any example or any other way i can implement this kind of problem..

Comment: I will write it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a basic Collision Detection problem.

Basically what you want to do is of course listen to the screen touches and receive the X & Y of the touch location. (You can of course use multi-touch, just remember to do this for every touch)

When a touch appears you will calculate a bunch of `containsRectanglePoint` for each key on the image.

So basically you will split the image into a lot of rectangles like so.

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/df5e0493c7d284221b55de05a07a84c5.png))</sub>

Then you check if the point contains any of the rectangles.

- If the touch X & Y is inside either 1 or 2 then perform the event for that key.
- If the touch X & Y is inside either 3, 4 or 5 the perform the event for that key.
- If the touch X & Y is inside either 6 then perform the event for that key.
- If the touch X & Y is inside either 7 then perform the event for that key.

You will of course do that for all the keys.

So thereby when a collision happens you look through all that.

#### Simple Rectangle vs Point Collision Detection

The following code checks for collision detection between a rectangle and a point. If the point is within the rectangles bounds then the method will return true. If not it returns false.

```
public static boolean containsRectanglePoint(double x, double y, double w, double h, double px, double py)
{
    if (px < x) { return false; }
    if (py < y) { return false; }
    if (px > (x + w)) { return false; }
    if (py > (y + h)) { return false; }
    
    return true;
}
```

- `x` = Rectangle X (or AABB Minimum X)
- `y` = Rectangle Y (or AABB Minimum Y)
- `w` = Rectangle Width (or AABB Maximum X - AABB Minimum X)
- `h` = Rectangle Height (or AABB Maximum Y - AABB Minimum Y)
- `px` = Point X
- `py` = Point Y

In your case `px` & `py` is the location of the touch.

*You could also use Java's standard `Rectangle2D` class, to both store and calculate the collisions, but that requires creating a lot of instances of the class, and it will be a lot cheaper, when we are talking about memory, to just store the coordinates and then use the function I provided to you.*